# Can I use a struct in a way that does not exist in the header file implementation?

Tags: c, struct, header-files

So I am a Java and C# person recently doing some stuff C. I have a header file that would have a function `void update(struct process* foo, float measurements)` and in the implementation of the header file (the .c file) I will have the function:

```
void update(struct process* p,float measurements)
{
  *p.speed = *p.speed + measurements;
  *p.time = *p.time + 1;
  *p.noise = *p.noise + ((measurements)/100);
}
```

Now in Java I would have to import the class process and it would be all good. However in the .c implementation how would I do that without declaring the struct in the .c file (which would be pointless since I want to pass parameter from another module using it)?

I am quite new in C and may be it's  a very basic question but I did an hour search in internet ended up not finding what I am looking for. Maybe my keywords were just poorly chosen.

Comment: Maybe something's not clear, but you normally put all your declarations in your header files.

Comment: `#include "process.h"` `process` is it there?

Comment: In your implementation file (.c) add at the top add:
#include "yourheaderfile.h" (replace yourheaderfile with the name of the file)

Comment: You probably also want `(*p).` or `p->` instead of `*p.`, since the `.` operator has higher precedence than the the `*` operator.

Comment: Thanks! So I need to declare another header file to declare the structure? I was thinking about that but then I was afraid of circular reference.

Comment: @AusCBloke Thanks! I am a newbie in C so need to catch up a lot.

Comment: @ArunavDev I think you should read a C book before proceeding, here is a [list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include the file where `process` structure definition is.

As @AusCBloke noticed, you'll either use `(*p).` to dereference struct pointer and access its member, or `p->` which is syntactic sugar for `(*p).`

Comment: Just like Java I guess I would need to create another class then which would be a header file. I was trying to avoid writing another header file just for a new structure.